# Laravel 4 RESTful API - Passing Validation Errors to View

Tags: php, validation, rest, laravel

I'm working with a team that recently re-coded our project with a RESTful API.

Previous I used to pass in validation errors by using:

```
return Redirect::to('add_clientes_error')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());
```

And in the view I displayed it using (blade):

```
{{ $errors->first('name') }}
```

Now after the re-factoring the view is created with:

```
return Redirect::to('add_clientes_error')->withErrors($response['errors'])->withInput(Input::all());
```

...and I can see the $errors array since I am printing it out on the view which looks like this:

```
 Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag Object ( [bags:protected] => Array ( [default] => Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object ( [messages:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [field] => name [message] => The name field is required. ) ) [format:protected] => :message ) ) ) 1
```

My question is...how do I echo the variables now because `{{ $errors->first('name') }}` is empty.  I know the message is no longer the "first" element in the array but not sure how to get to the message element.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$errors->getBag('default')` as the array containing the errors and then retrieve the error items by using normal array notation. So for example:

```
$errors_array = $errors->getBag('default');
$name_error = $errors_array['name'][0]; // to get the first error on the name field
```

Comment: Makes sense, however since I need to do that in my controller and pass $errors_array into my view, how do I extract $errors from the bigger $validator array that Laravel uses?